# Is it possible to override both default style and queries in Neo4j data browser? (2.3.2)

Tags: neo4j, server

How can the default style sheet and example queries of the Neo4j **Data Browser** be customized? (version 2.3.2)
Is it possible to do it so that the *default* state of the data browser is changed?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. In the left sidebar of Neo4j Browser there is "Styling / Graph Style sheet"

There you can modify or download style sheet for the visualization.

http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-neo4j-browser/

Comment: That only changes the "local" version of the style sheet, I mean having it changed so that any new user that connects to the server for the first time can also see the data browser with the customized version of the style sheet applied